# Decimal to binary self challenge

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to write a small program that converts a decimal to binary that doesn't use the inbuilt function that do that. My program won't convert anything over 12287. 12288 just spits out an infinite loop. Where have I gone wrong? why can't I get above 12287?

```
    while (number != 1) or (number != 0):
        a = number // 2
        b = number % 2
        number = a
        if b == 0:
            output = "0" + output
            if number == 1:
                output = "1" + output
                break
        else:
            output = "1" + output
```

Comment: `(number != 1) or (number != 0)` is always `True`.  If you let `number` get to be `0`, there is no way for the loop to end (as the only other way out is for `number` to be `1` when `b` is `0`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the condition from:

```
while (number != 1) or (number != 0):
```

To:

```
while number != 0:
```

Other than that, your code looks OK.  Here is a more streamlined version of the same basic idea:

```
output = ""
while number:
    number, b = divmod(number, 2)
    output = str(b) + output
```

Comment: Thank you, that's got it working well, now I'm off to try and break it.

Answer (score 0):

For 12288, `number` eventually becomes `0`. This means `while` condition is always `True`.

Note that `b` becomes `0`, so number will stay at `0`.